# How do I add multiple serviceworkers in SvelteKit?

Tags: service-worker, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to add a second serviceworker to my SvelteKit application, but it needs to keep the same scope. I read that that's possible, by just calling two register operations. I do that, but it doesn't work anyway. This is because SvelteKit only compiles the serviceworker script with the path `src/service-worker.{ts/js}` but not something like `src/other-sw.ts`.

How do I make SvelteKit compile both serviceworkers so I can register them both?

Comment: Doesn't seem supported. You can create another entry point for the second service worker via the `vite.config.js`, but the resulting file exists outside the Svelte Kit build system and gets thrown into the server-side part of the code, at least with the Node adapter.